# Rear axle swap on Mavic hub

Tags: wheels

Is it possible to change the rear axle from a 12x142 thru axle to a 9x135 qr on a Mavic Ksyrium wheel?

Comment: I want to say there are no through axle Ksyriums or Akskiums that aren't convertible, but there are always so many generations with Mavic that it's hard to keep track.

Comment: @Mark I'd email your question to Mavic.

Answer (score 1):

https://shop.mavic.com/en-gb/ksyrium-disc-rr0889.html#1028=3283

> **Compatibility**
>
> Rear axle: 12mm thru axle, convertible to Quick Release with optional adapters (not available in Germany)

This listing offers various adapters, including a QR option, which may fit your hub:
https://shop.mavic.com/en-gb/rear-axle-adapters-oc0672.html#1040=3808

Comment: Wonder why the adapters are not available in Germany.  The whole EU I could understand but specifically Germany ?

Comment: Couldn't find an explanation, but I did find a German retailer selling them: https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/mavic-9%2C5mm-rearaxle-adapters-from-12mm-to-9%2C5mm-from-2012-60857/wg_id-4538